# how to get all css properties using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, html

I have divs. They can be drag, resizable and i have a div editor.That means i can change any div width,height,margin,padding and it background-color,font-size,font-weight etc.I done this using jquery and i did it perfectly.Now what i want to know How i get all css properties with the each div.

When i done using jquery each div element,style properties changing...

```
element.style{
width:250px;
height:35px;
top:233.23px;
left:33.12px;
background-color:#000;
font-size:16px;
font-weight:600;


}
```

like that.So i want to get all above values to the jquery object to create json file.How can i achieve this ?

Comment: have you tried using `jquery.css()` ??

Comment: Created a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/TFaZ3/ -- From this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element

Comment: @bipen no i didn't try it yet

Answer (score 2):

Based on this answer: [Can jQuery get all CSS styles associated with an element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/754607/can-jquery-get-all-css-styles-associated-with-an-element)

Here's a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tymeJV/TFaZ3/

The result `console.log(css($(".test")));` ==  `Object {600: "", width: "250px", height: "35px", top: "233.23px", left: "33.12px", background-color: "rgb(0, 0, 0)"…}`

Seems to accomplish what is needed.

Comment: cool.. but then you forgot to add the `function css(){...` here.. without that i doubt this will work.. i assume, you 'll get an error saying `css is not defined` ... :)

Answer (score 0):

You use must first set a class with CSS and then use 'addClass' instead of 'css' with jQuery.
See the example I have below:

.class {margin:0; padding:0; text-align:center; }

And then you jQuery would look something like this:

(function() {
        $('selector').addClass('class'); 
    })(jQuery);